# Why the measurable space need to be defined as an ordered pair $(X,\mathcal S)$ instead of just $\mathcal S$ itself?

Tags: measure-theory, definition

I'm reading this book [1] and met the definition of a measurable space:

> A *measurable space* is an ordered pair $(X,\mathcal S)$, where $X$ is a set and $\mathcal S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$.

**My question is**, why does the measurable space need to be defined as an ordered pair $(X,\mathcal S)$ instead of just $\mathcal S$ itself since $\mathcal S$ itself contains the whole set $X$ as one element?

For example, let's consider the set $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $\mathcal S=\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\emptyset,\{1,2,3,4\}\}$. I think the information of $X$ itself is also contained in $\mathcal S$. Hence the $X$ in the definition of a measurable space is redundant?

<sup>[1]: Measure, Integration & Real Analysis by Sheldon Axler</sup>

Comment: Technically yes. But the definition of $\sigma$-algebra depends on the set $X$ to begin with, since you need the whole space $X$ in order to say $\mathcal{S}$ is closed under taking complements.

Comment: It seems preferable to write let $(X,\mathcal S)$ be a measurable space, compared to let $\mathcal S$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. It is perhaps not obvious now that the former flows better, but here is one example to try and convince you. Let $(X,\mathcal X)$ and $(Y,\mathcal Y)$ be measurable spaces; versus let $\mathcal X$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ and $\mathcal Y$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$.